# How to filter query results by url prefix in SPARQL?

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

This is the query I have,

```
PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>

SELECT ?p ?x
WHERE
{ 
  dbr:Australia ?p ?x 
}
```

I need only URI in the results. `x` and `p` should be in the format of `http://dbpedia.org/resource/something` and  `http://dbpedia.org/property/something`. Please help me to go through this.

Comment: `filter(strstarts(str(?p), "http://dbpedia.org/property/"))` - analogous for `?x`

Comment: `filter regex(?p, "dbpedia.org/property")
  filter regex(?x, "dbpedia.org/resource")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=&qtxt=PREFIX%20dbr%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT%20%3Fp%20%3Fx%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20dbr%3AAustralia%20%3Fp%20%3Fx%20%0D%0A%20%20FILTER%20%28%20STRSTARTS%20%28%20STR%20%28%20%3Fp%20%29%2C%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fproperty%2F%22%20%29%20%29%0D%0A%20%20FILTER%20%28%20STRSTARTS%20%28%20STR%20%28%20%3Fx%20%29%2C%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2F%22%20%29%20%29%0D%0A%7D%0D%0AORDER%20BY%20%3Fp%20%3Fx&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&signal_void=on&signal_unconnected=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20) will get [what you're asking for](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=&query=PREFIX%20dbr%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT%20%3Fp%20%3Fx%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20dbr%3AAustralia%20%3Fp%20%3Fx%20%0D%0A%20%20FILTER%20%28%20STRSTARTS%20%28%20STR%20%28%20%3Fp%20%29%2C%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fproperty%2F%22%20%29%20%29%0D%0A%20%20FILTER%20%28%20STRSTARTS%20%28%20STR%20%28%20%3Fx%20%29%2C%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2F%22%20%29%20%29%0D%0A%7D%0D%0AORDER%20BY%20%3Fp%20%3Fx&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&signal_void=on&signal_unconnected=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20) --

```
PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>

SELECT ?p ?x
WHERE
{ 
  dbr:Australia ?p ?x 
  FILTER ( STRSTARTS ( STR ( ?p ), "http://dbpedia.org/property/" ) )
  FILTER ( STRSTARTS ( STR ( ?x ), "http://dbpedia.org/resource/" ) )
}
ORDER BY ?p ?x
```

The [results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=PREFIX%20dbr%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT%20%3Fp%20%3Fx%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20dbr%3AAustralia%20%3Fp%20%3Fx%20%0D%0A%20%20FILTER%20%28%20ISURI%20%28%20%3Fp%20%29%20%29%0D%0A%20%20FILTER%20%28%20ISURI%20%28%20%3Fx%20%29%20%29%0D%0A%7D%0D%0AORDER%20BY%20%3Fp%20%3Fx&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20) of [the following](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=PREFIX%20dbr%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT%20%3Fp%20%3Fx%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20dbr%3AAustralia%20%3Fp%20%3Fx%20%0D%0A%20%20FILTER%20%28%20ISURI%20%28%20%3Fp%20%29%20%29%0D%0A%20%20FILTER%20%28%20ISURI%20%28%20%3Fx%20%29%20%29%0D%0A%7D%0D%0AORDER%20BY%20%3Fp%20%3Fx&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20) might be better, though it doesn't restrict all URIs to the two prefixes you've wished for.  Note that the next update of the DBpedia dataset (partially visible now on [the DBpedia-Live endpoint](https://live.dbpedia.org/sparql)) will change much of the data, and `http://dbpedia.org/property/` will no longer be the prefix for most of Australia's attributes/predicates --

```
PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>

SELECT ?p ?x
WHERE
{ 
  dbr:Australia ?p ?x 
  FILTER ( ISURI ( ?p ) )
  FILTER ( ISURI ( ?x ) )
}
ORDER BY ?p ?x
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @TallTed